# get the key of the minimum value of a dictionary which in turn the key is in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, min

I want to get the key that has the minimum value in a given dictionary, but with the condition that this key is in a given list

for example this would be the dictionary.

```py
dict = {
    's': 0,
    'y': 5,
    't': 8,
    'z': 7,
    'x': 9
}
```

and this is the list with the keys to be checked

```py
list = ['y', 'z', 't', 'x']
```

I made this implementation, but I think it could be optimized or made in a more pythonic way.

```py
a = float("inf")
for key in dict:
    if key in list:
        temp=a
        a = min(a,dict[key])
        if a < temp:
            minimum = key
```

Comment: There's potential for ambiguity here. In your dictionary, change the value for 't' to 5. Now, what would be the required key? 't' or 'y'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `min` with `dct.get`:

```
>>> min(lst, key=dct.get)
'y'
>>>
```

This get's the minimum value in `lst` based o n the value of that key in the `dct` dictionary.

P.S. I renamed `dict` to `dct` and `list` to `lst`, so you don't override the variable names.

#### Edit:

As @Ch3steR mentioned, if there are any keys not in the dictionary that are in `lst`.

You could use:

```
min(lst, key=lambda x: dct.get(x, float('inf')))
```

Or you could use @Ch3steR's approach, with:

```
min(dct.keys() & lst, key=dct.get)
'y'
```

But I implemented my own `type`, named `mydict`, which you can use, it has `dict` inherited just it also has a `__missing__` magic method definition, so it will give `float('inf')` (infinity) if the key doesn't exist. Let's say `lst` becomes:

```
lst = ['y', 'z', 't', 'x', 'key that does not exist']
```

Then you inherit `mydict` type:

```
mydict = type('mydict', (dict,), {'__missing__': lambda self, key: float('inf'),})
```

And now you can use `__getitem__` directly:

```
>>> min(lst, key=mydict(dct).__getitem__)
'y'
>>>
```

The same `mydict` type could be inherited with:

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return float('inf')
```

And it would work too.

Comment: But if an extra key exists this approach would raise an error for e.g lst is `lst = ['y', 'z', 't', 'x', 'aa']`

Comment: PS: not the downvoter.

Comment: @Ch3steR Just decided to do something funny :) check it out

Comment: You've covered everything I deleted my answer. I was thinking can we use `functools.partial`?

Comment: @Ch3steR Ok! Will try

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using **List Comprehension**:

```
dict = {
    's': 0,
    'y': 5,
    't': 8,
    'z': 7,
    'x': 9
}
list = ['y', 'z', 't', 'x'] 
temp =min([j for i,j in dict.items() if i in list])     ##output - 5
res = [i for i,j in dict.items() if dict[i]==temp]      
print(*res)
```

Output:

```
y
```